# async/await .map error after receiving data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, redux-saga

I'm very new to async/await, so please bear with me. I'm making an api GET request like so:

```
import { identity } from 'ramda';
export const fetchOrders = async (api: Client) => {
  const orders = await api.get(orderHistoryUrl).then(getData(identity))
```

Which returns me an array of objects:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Inside each of these objects is an `id` that I want to retrieve and save that into a variable. I've tried something like this:

```
const billing = orders.map(order => order.id)
```

but `.map` doesn't seem to work with an error of `[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'.`

I thought orders was a type of Array?  I even tried something like:

```
const billing = await orders.map(order => ....)

const billing = orders.map(await order => ....)
```

but they all seem to have the same error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is `getData` ? And what is `identity` good for? And how do you know that `Which returns me an array of objects` ?

Comment: I would avoid using then, with await.

Comment: @JonasWilms `getData` is just a helper since this is an axios instance making the request, so I don't need to call something like `data.data` twice, and paired with `identity` to get me the data (not my codebase).

Comment: `[ts]` means this is a typescript error. That isnt a runtime problem, but the types are wrong.